# PostgreSQL user creation and linkage to login as it is in SQL Server

Tags: sql, postgresql

In SQL Server, I can have Login level account and User account(in particular database). So, I can show the relationship using this SQL statement in SQL Server:

```
SELECT @DBUser = a.[name]
FROM sys.database_principals dp
RIGHT JOIN sys.sql_logins sl ON dp.sid = sl.sid
```

I would like to create a user for a particular database in my PostgreSQL and give permissions for `SELECT`, `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` operations.

In SQL Server I can do this in this way:

```
-- login was created before
CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyUser

IF (IS_ROLEMEMBER('db_datareader', MyUser) = 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', MyUser
END

IF (IS_ROLEMEMBER('db_datawriter', MyUser) = 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter',MyUser
END
```

But how can I do the similar task in PostgreSQL correctly?

Comment: You can get examples from the documentation for [creating users](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-createuser.html) and [granting permissions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-grant.html).  I am not sure, however, if there are Postgres equivalents of db_datareader and db_datawriter.

Comment: While not directly related you might want to take few minuets and read [Migrate your mindset too](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PostGreSQL does not have two level security (at the Instance level with login and at the db level with user) like SQL Server... There is only user in databases.
2. There is not builtin role in PostGreSQL like the one you have at Instance or DB level. You must create those role and apply them to the SQL users you want
3. by the way sp_addrolemember is a deprecacted feature in MS SQL Server and must not be use... The Transact SQL command to do that is :

   ALTER ROLE ... ADD MEMBER ...